# Check two columns for numbers and output the number found into the third column

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a simply equation that will check two cells that are side by side and output the one that contain numbers into the third column. Example:

```
abc   123    = 123
def   789    = 789
456   lmn    = 456
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is in columns A and B:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,IF(ISNUMBER(B1),B1,"No Numbers Found"))
```

The formula will display "No Numbers Found" if neither contain a number.

**Edit:**

If your numbers are not formatted as numbers, try this instead:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(INT(A1))),A1,IF(NOT(ISERROR(INT(B1))),B1,"No Numbers Found"))
```

Comment: Will this work if the values that are generated are from a vlookup?

Comment: When i use this equation with constants it works perfectly but with my values generated from vlookup i always receive "no numbers found". any thoughts?

Comment: I edited with an alternate formula you can use in the event that your numbers are not formatted as numbers.